# Apache Ignite Table created in transactional mode does not support commit and rollback feature

Tags: java, sql, ignite

I have created 2 tables using create sql query according to the ignite syntax in replicated and transactional mode. I am using IgniteJdbcDriver to get the connection. Now I need to perform DML transactions over those tables. But commit and rollback transactions over connection object are not supported by ignite driver. Getting exception as "Transaction not suppoerted"
Please help me with the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you include a code snippet you're more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Please take a look at this documentation, specifically "transactionsAllowed" property: https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/jdbc-client-driver#section-jdbc-client-driver